# Understanding instance/cpu/utilization of Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm new with Google Compute Engine and I don't understand the metric instance/cpu/utilization on axis=0 or y. 
The scale as I see it goes up to 0,15. That means the CPU usage is only 15%?

My instance has 24 CPUs because I'm trying to run a really big pandas groupby().mean() and it's taking forever. 
It's a Jupyter notebook. Should I run extra code to make the whole instance to work? 
Maybe I'm paying too much for the instance if it wont run fully.

I was expecting to run full load

Comment: When you say 0.15, do you mean 0.15%, or you mean 0.15 (relative to 1.00)?  In the compute engine console for me, CPU usage is indicated on the chart in percent.  My instances show ~0.15% when they are not in use at all (i.e. idle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking on the Instance name on GCP Console and then clicking on the tab "Monitoring" you will be able to see the CPU usage on %.

Anyway If you are using Google Cloud Platform I strongly recommend you use the Stackdriver Monitoring [1] feature which is very nice (also compatible with AWS), if you also are able to install the agent [2] you will get a lot of metrics which can be useful later.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent

Comment: Let me know if I can be of further help!.

Comment: Damian i am collecting timeseries metrics for cpu utilization of instances. I am getting values like this "metricKind": "GAUGE",
      "valueType": "DOUBLE",
      "points": [
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-23T07:26:02.603Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-23T07:26:02.603Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 0.091223128743965293
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "unit": "10^2.%" > in the end unit is given as 100% so should i multiply this             "doubleValue": 0.091223128743965293 by 100 ?