# Is there a way I can get current CPU utilization of a VM on GCE using 'gcloud' commands?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am new to GCE. I am trying to write a cron job to take some action based on current CPU utilization of some VMs on GCE. Is there a way I can get this info using 'gcloud' command?

I have tried `gcloud compute instances describe <instance_name>`. But that does not provide current CPU utilization info.

I found this other post that talks about getting this info from StackDriver - [Understanding instance/cpu/utilization of Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175192/understanding-instance-cpu-utilization-of-google-compute-engine)

I am looking for this info using 'gcloud'.

Appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcloud commands are used to create and manage Google Cloud resources. I checked the gcloud command references and it does't cover monitoring metric. To monitor performance of your VM instance, you need to use stackdriver monitoring

If you really want this feature in gcloud command, you can open a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com)